# Can we exclude an element from a set if it satisfies all the properties of the set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For e.g., let $A = \{n \in \mathbb{N} \,:\, 1 < n < 5\}.$ Are $\{2,3,4\}$ and $\{2\}$ both valid?

In such cases, I have been using the set with all elements satisfying the property. But $\{2\}$ seems valid too, since $(2 \in \mathbb{N}) \,\land\, (1 < 2 < 5)$. Is there any rule as to when our definition implicitly means the case "for all"?

Comment: Yea, the notation is shorthand for "for all"

Comment: Does that mean $A \neq \{2\}$?

Comment: $A$ is certainly bigger than $\{2\}$.  The general meaning of this [set builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) is to describe what elements belong to a set.  The set $A$, from its description, contains an element not contained in $\{2\}$.  The principle (axiom) of extensionality says the two sets are not equal (because they do not contain precisely the same elements).

Comment: To add on to @hardmath's comment, Set Builder notation usually refers to the set existence specified by the axiom schema of specification.

Comment: It wouldn't be very useful notation if it could mean two things.  The set $A = \{n \in \mathbb{N} \,:\, 1 < n < 5\}$ means "the set of all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1 < n< 5$."  Every number that satisfies the condition is part of the set, and only those.

Comment: The use of $=$ should be helpful here: it doesn't make sense to write both $A = \{n \in \mathbb{N} \,:\, 1 < n < 5\} = \{2,3,4\}$ and  $A = \{n \in \mathbb{N} \,:\, 1 < n < 5\} = \{2\}$ as that would imply $\{2,3,4\} = \{2\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't exclude any element from a set if it satisfies all the properties.  The set builder notation you used implicitly means "for all". Set builder notation is supposed to describe a unique set and if you could exclude random elements then it would no longer be unique.